# How do I flash zip Visual Studio Android Emulator using console/adb.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

How do I flash zip the Visual Studio Android Emulator using console (adb)? I would like to install the cyanogen mod on it to get google apps on.

I have tried dragging and dropping the zip file and it does not allow me. I also checked on this [troubleshooting guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#DragAndDrop) but it seems the path is pointing to the correct path of the Android SDK tools already.

I'm using Windows 8.1 with VS 2015 Pro and VS Android Emulator. Note that I was able to do the flashing on my laptop with Windows 10 / VS 2015 Community by just dragging and dropping the zip file so I'm not sure if Windows version has something to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this blog post](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com.au/2015/06/manually-install-google-apps-on-hyper-v.html).

1. Download the [GApps](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) packages specific for the Android version your emulator is running
2. Unzip the file
3. Open an adb command prompt (if you have the Xamarin Tools installed in Visual Studio 2015 open the menu Tools->Android->Android Adb Command Prompt) and navigate where you have unzipped your files.
4. Go to the system folder in the extracted archive
5. Execute this set of commands:

> adb remount
>
> adb shell chmod 777 /system
>
> adb push . /system